# XNA 2D TileEngine Mouse clicking issue

Tags: c#, xna

My problem is that clicks only get registers on the lower right corner and in some cases not even there it seems to get worse the longer you stray from the 0.0 and the likes the worse it gets.

```
   public void Render(SpriteBatch B, Camera C)
    {
        Vector2 firstSquare = new Vector2(C.Position.X / 32, C.Position.Y / 32);
        int firstX = (int)firstSquare.X;
        int firstY = (int)firstSquare.Y;

        Vector2 squareOffset = new Vector2(C.Position.X % 32, C.Position.Y % 32);
        int offsetX = (int)squareOffset.X;
        int offsetY = (int)squareOffset.Y;
        for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
            {
                Tile T = GetTile(x + firstX, y + firstY);
                if (T == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                T.RenderWithCamera(B,new Vector2((x*32)-offsetX,(y*32)-offsetY));

            }
        }   
   public void CheckClick(float mx, float my,Camera C)
    {
        Vector2 firstSquare = new Vector2(C.Position.X / 32, C.Position.Y / 32);
        int x = (int)firstSquare.X;
        int y = (int)firstSquare.Y;
        Vector2 squareOffset = new Vector2(C.Position.X % 32, C.Position.Y % 32);
        int offsetX = (int)squareOffset.X;
        int offsetY = (int)squareOffset.Y;
        int vx = (int)mx / 32;
        int vy = (int)my / 32;
        float x1 = vx + x;
        float y1 = vy + y;
        int maxX, maxY;
        maxX = C.Width / 32;
        maxY = C.Height / 32;
        Console.WriteLine("MAX_X:" + maxX + "MAX_Y:" + maxY);
        Tile T = GetTile(x1, y1);
        Rectangle A = new Rectangle((int)mx, (int)my, 1, 1);
        if (T == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("No Tile found"); return; }
        if (T.IsInside(A))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not inside?");
            Tile S = null;
            S = new Wall((int)x1, (int)y1, 0);
            if (S != null)
            {

                tiles.Add(S);
                tiles2[(int)T.pos.X, (int)T.pos.Y] = S;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked Tile at X:" + T.pos.X + "Y:" + T.pos.Y);
    }
    public bool IsInside(Rectangle B) // TILE
    {
        Rectangle rectA = new Rectangle((int)Last_pos.X, (int)Last_pos.Y, icon.Width, icon.Height);

        Console.WriteLine("A:" + rectA.X + "A.y:" + rectA.Y + "B.X:" + B.X + "B.Y:" + B.Y);
        if(rectA.Intersects(B))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Where is `CheckClick` called from? Seems like wherever it's called from will be the perpetrating code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I like to handle clicking a tilemap.

```
int xTile = Math.floor((Mouse.X + CameraBounds.left) / Tile.width);
int yTile = Math.floor((Mouse.Y + CameraBounds.top) / Tile.height);
```